# Integrating Next.js 13 App with Auth0, Supabase, and Row-Level Security

Tags: next.js

I'm currently working on integrating Auth0 and Supabase into my Next.js application by following a tutorial. Auth0 integration is working well, but I'd like to incorporate Supabase and implement row-level security in my application.

I'm encountering an issue with accessing the 'sub' attribute in the session, as well as updating the 'accessToken' since it appears that session.user is undefined.

Is there a specific way to correctly access the 'sub' attribute and update the 'accessToken' within the session when working with Auth0 and Supabase integration in a Next.js app? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://auth0.com/blog/using-nextjs-and-auth0-with-supabase/#Row-Level-Security

```
    const afterCallback = async (req, res, session) => {
      const payload = {
        userId: session.user.sub,
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60,
      };

      session.user.accessToken = jwt.sign(
        payload,
        process.env.SUPABASE_SIGNING_SECRET
      );

      return session;
    };
```

I have tried this on a fresh Next13 App using the App router and the Pages router.

Answer (score 0):

It works a bit different in app router: https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/types/handlers_callback.AfterCallbackAppRoute.html

Try this

```
const afterCallback = (req, session, state) => {

 const payload = {
   userId: session.user.sub,
   exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60,
 };

session.user.accessToken = jwt.sign(
  payload,
  process.env.SUPABASE_SIGNING_SECRET
);

  return session;
};

export const GET = handleAuth({
 callback: handleCallback({ afterCallback }),
});
```